# Adding multiple balls on canvas onclick

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to implement a moving ball animation in HTML5 canvas. I want to generate a ball whenever I click on the canvas. (The position and displacement velocity will be random).

But the problem is that, whenever I am clicking on the canvas, a ball appears, but the velocity of the previous ball also changes. I know that it is happening because I running the same loop again.

Can someone suggest me a logic for this?

I have tried the below code.

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('ballCanvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let animBalls = [];
const animBallsColor = ['red','green','yellow']


ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 800);

const Ball = function(bx,by,dx,dy,br = 10,color = "red",bv=0){

  this.bx = bx;
  this.by = by;
  this.bv = bv;
  this.br = br;
  this.dx = dx;
  this.dy = dy;
  this.color = color;
}

canvas.addEventListener('click', () => {
  animBalls.push(new Ball(
    Math.floor((Math.random() * 400) + 1),
    Math.floor((Math.random() * 500)),
    Math.floor((Math.random() * 5)),
    Math.floor((Math.random() * 3))
  ))
  console.log(animBalls)
  setInterval(run,10)

  if(animBalls.length > 10){
    canvas.removeEventListener('click', ()=>{
      console.log('quit')
    })
  }
})

function run(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,600,500);
  animBalls.forEach(function(ball){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = ball.color;
    ctx.arc(ball.bx,ball.by,ball.br,0,Math.PI * 2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    ball.bx+=ball.dx;
    ball.by+=ball.dy;
   if(ball.bx<0 || ball.bx>canvas.width){
    ball.dx = -ball.dx
  }

   if(ball.by<0 || ball.by>canvas.height){
     ball.dy = -ball.dy;
   }
  })
```

Comment: put your `SetInteval` outside of click listener and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

The issue is at `setInterval(run, 10)` inside the click handler. Every time you click you're starting a new interval calling run every 10ms

If you just take it out of the click handler and call it once your thing works :)

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('ballCanvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let animBalls = [];
const animBallsColor = ['red','green','yellow']


ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 800);

const Ball = function(bx,by,dx,dy,br = 10,color = "red",bv=0){

  this.bx = bx;
  this.by = by;
  this.bv = bv;
  this.br = br;
  this.dx = dx;
  this.dy = dy;
  this.color = color;
}

canvas.addEventListener('click', () => {
  animBalls.push(new Ball(
    Math.floor((Math.random() * 400) + 1),
    Math.floor((Math.random() * 500)),
    Math.floor((Math.random() * 5)),
    Math.floor((Math.random() * 3))
  ))
  console.log(animBalls)

  if(animBalls.length > 10){
    canvas.removeEventListener('click', ()=>{
      console.log('quit')
    })
  }
})

function run(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,600,500);
  animBalls.forEach(function(ball){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = ball.color;
    ctx.arc(ball.bx,ball.by,ball.br,0,Math.PI * 2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    ball.bx+=ball.dx;
    ball.by+=ball.dy;
   if(ball.bx<0 || ball.bx>canvas.width){
    ball.dx = -ball.dx
  }

   if(ball.by<0 || ball.by>canvas.height){
     ball.dy = -ball.dy;
   }
  })
}

setInterval(run,10)
```